# What does "I'm trying to pick up trade" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The movie is Tau.

That is what the English subtitle says. Maybe an "a" missing from the subtitles? "trying to pick up A trade"? surrounding dialogue:

> - What's wrong with her?
>   - Maybe the thing fried her brain.
>   - Do you know what it's for? This thing.
>   - I don't know. One night I'm out trying to pick up trade and next thing I know I wake up in this place. What about you?

(the person who said this has been kidnapped)

Please native English speakers, help me understand this expression.
Thank you

Comment: More context please.  Who said this? When? Where?  Please use [edit] to edit your question. Make sure the body contains the full question, and tells us what you have done already (eg which dictionaries you have used)

Comment: The movie is Tau.

Comment: That is what the English subtitle says. Maybe an "a" missing from the subtitles? "trying to pick up A trade"?
surrounding dialogue:
"- What's wrong with her?
- Maybe the thing fried her brain.
- Do you know what it's for? This thing.
- I don't know. One night I'm out trying to pick up trade and next thing I know 
I wake up in this place. What about you?"

Answer (score 1):

"Trade" is a mass noun, and doesn't usually take "a". (It can be a count noun in the sense of "an individual swap or transaction").

"Pick up trade" here means "get some customers" - I assume she is a prostitute. (I don't know anything about the film in question - I'm just basing this one what you've told us above).

Answer (score -1):

lol i just looked this up because I assume I am watching the same movie on netflix you did. I would assume based upon the context and all that...the guy was a hooker and he meant he was looking for people to pay him for sex.